# Powdered milk in bread recipe

Tags: substitutions, bread, milk

I have a book with several bread recipes that call for 1-2 tablespoons of powdered milk. This isn't something I usually use and I was thinking substituting it with normal milk, and putting less water to compensate for the added liquid. Would this be ok? And if yes, how much milk should I put for one tablespoon of powdered milk?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A general reconstitution of milk with dried powder is 1/4 dry milk and 1 cup water to reconstitute milk.  So 2 tablespoons is 1/8 cup to 1/2 cup of water.

If you want to replace 2 tablespoons, replace 1/2 cup water with milk.  1 Tablespoon is 1/4 cup milk instead of water.

I have done this as a replacement for dried milk in bread many times with success.

Comment: Yep; note that dried milk is normally non-fat, so if you want a perfectly accurate substitution, use skim milk. But really it won't matter if you use whole, the bread will be a tiny bit richer.

Comment: So why do recipes (not for the bread maker) often call for powdered milk?

Comment: Does someone know what the conversion would be by weight? I don't know the density of milk powder so this doesn't help me bake by weight.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can. I use the King Arthur Flour Small Pain de Mie recipe all the time http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/a-smaller-pain-de-mie-recipe, which calls for non-fat powdered milk. An answer to another question here [Why is milk powder used in bread machine recipes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/why-is-milk-powder-used-in-bread-machine-recipes) says to scald the milk, a concept reiterated by the folks at King Arthur. So as an experiment, I made two loaves of bread, identical in every way except that in one I substituted 170 ml scalded skim milk for the powdered milk and that volume of water.

[image: 2 loaves]

Right out of the oven and three days later, I can find no difference between the two loaves of bread.

My package of powdered milk calls for 7 ounces of water to 1/3 cup powder to make 1 cup of milk, so I figured 8 tsp powder + 7 Tbs water = 1/2 cup milk. I converted to metric just to make the math easier, but it doesn't seem to me to require that much precision.

Answer (score 8):

One thing to add to the answers mentioned before: if you leave the ingredients in a bread machine overnight, then powdered milk is better as it doesn't go sour.

Comment: back when I used a bread machine, this is why I had powdered milk.

Comment: The more you know... I've never owned a bread machine so this is new to me. Never knew you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can substitute as already answered, but you can also just leave it out! I've found it makes no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave it out - least in those quantities. We make bread in a bread maker with and without it, and *anecdotally* adding it tends to make for softer, less chewy bread, especially if its a recipe with some sort of fat in it.

Comment: "We make bread in a bread maker with and without it, and anecdotally it tends to make for softer, less chewy bread". I'm sorry, which makes it softer? Including milk powder? Or leaving it out?