# Does breadmaker bread need to include milk powder?

Tags: bread, vegan

I'm trying to make vegan bread but all of my bread maker machine's recipies have one or two tablespoons of milk powder. What is a vegan solution?

Comment: Thank you Dougal. Great link and so quickly supplied :-)

Comment: Not a problem, actually they looked good enough for us non-vegans, so I will have to say thank you for the question.

Comment: Bread is vegan by default, milk or milk powder is a rare ingredient.

Comment: GdD. Great info.

Comment: @SJF , welcome to the site! Let me encourage you to take the [tour] and browse our [help] for more information on how the site and the whole Stack Exchange system works. We usually avoid "thanks messages" (nevertheless I appreciate yours below). Our mechanisms to express agreement are votes and, if we are the askers, usually accepting one answer. The latter not being mandatory, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is milk powder used in bread machine recipes?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/why-is-milk-powder-used-in-bread-machine-recipes)

Answer (score 6):

A basic bread is

- flour
- water
- yeast or sourdough
- (salt)

With these base ingredients, just by varying flour type, ratios and preparation method, you already get a wide range of breads, whether made by hand, kneaded in a mixer or dumped in a bread maker.

Extra ingredients influence the crumb texture and / or the taste of your bread. Including some fat, for example, makes the crumb "fluffier", using milk instead of or in addition to water gives finer pores and alters the taste a bit.

If all recipes that came with your bread maker include milk powder, I'd assume this to be a quirk of the author, not a necessity. I'd simply leave it out. You *could* add a teaspoon or so of vegan fat, but I don't think it's essential, especially if your recipe already has some.

---

Feel free to ask more specific questions, if the results aren't what you'd want them to be.

Comment: The answers I have received are great

Comment: The answers I have recieved on this site have been great.

Comment: The answers I have received on this site have been great.
From those (tried multiple times) my fail-safe vegan bread machine bread is:
2.5 tsp yeast
437.5g HG flour
1T sugar
1.5 tsp salt
1.5 cups cold water
[In that order]
NON FAIL!